# $(window).load does not display images in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox

I am trying to write a script which displays a loader gif images while the image loads, but none of the images in the page in firefox after including the script. It works fine in chrome. I have included the following code.

Javascript:

```
<script>
$(window).load(function() {
    $('#loader').hide();
    $('#best').fadeIn();
});
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<body>
<div id="loader"></div> 
<div id="best"> 
<!-- Contents of the page here --> 
</div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
#loader {
    background: url('img/19-0.gif');
    height: 95px;
    width: 95px;
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: 15em;
    margin-left: 13em;
}

#best {
    display: none;
}
```

Is there any problems in my code or should I try an alternative approach?

Comment: is $(document).ready(function(){}); not working?

Comment: have you tried with a different pic format?

Comment: You have a typo in your css line, the last line of #loader (magrin-left: 13em;)

Comment: Could you please give some sort of feedback to our answers?

Comment: @ANonmousChange It worked on firefox. Cannot imagine it was a silly mistake that I couldn't think of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#loader').hide();
    $('#best').fadeIn();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
$('document').on("load", function() {

});
```

instead of `$(window).load()`.

Source: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: .load() (http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) has been deprecated use .on("load", function() {...} instead

Answer (score 0):

I hope you know, that for security reasons Firefox prevents user from loading local scripts and files loaded by scripts? Try using a local webserver instead.

Comment: I don't see any script code here loading in another script/file. Care to elaborate?

Comment: If the code, that he provided is full, then yes - there is nothing that load local files. I just wrote it in case, that there are any more lines of code, that he didn't wrote here.

Comment: Fair enough, since he did state that it doesn't work in Firefox but it does work in Chrome.